# MongoDB how to get K documents start from the middle of the collection in a single query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have `N` records which match a `query q` in a collection (eg. messages) of MongoDB. And I want to get the documents in range `[N/2, N/2 + 100)`.

Without knowing the value of `N`, I can do this by issue 2 query:

1. use `N = db.messages.find(q).count()` to get `N`, then compute the offset with `skipCount = N / 2 - 1`;
2. use `db.messages.find(q).skip(skipCount).limit(100)` to get the results

*Is there a way (especially in .net `MongoDB.Driver 2.7.2`) to merge the 2 query into a single one to improve the performance?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) operator to run more than one aggregation pipeline simultaneously and then process the result using result returned by multiple pipelines.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: q
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            count: [{ $count: "total" }],
            docs: [ { $match: q } ] // this is supposed to pass all input documents to the output but we can't specify empty array here thus we can repeat q
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$count"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            docs: {
                $slice: [ "$docs", { $multiply: [ -1, { $ceil: { $divide: [ "$count.total", 2 ] } } ] } ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$docs"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$docs"
        }
    }
])
```

Each stage defined in `$facet` will return an array however we know that count should contain only one element so we can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) on it. Second field (`docs`) will contain all the elements that were returned after `q` query. To take last `k` elements you can use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) passing negative value as second parameter (takes last `k` elements). Then you need to transformed sliced array back to original shape so you need `$unwind` and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html).

Since the aggregation is a bit complicated probably the best option in C# is to use `BsonDocument` class, try:

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> q = // your query

AggregateFacet<BsonDocument> countFacet = 
    AggregateFacet.Create<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>("count",
    PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] {
        new BsonDocumentPipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ $count: \"total\" }"))
    }));

AggregateFacet<BsonDocument> matchFacet =
    AggregateFacet.Create<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>("docs",
    PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] {
        PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(q)
    }));


var projection = new BsonDocumentProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument>(
    BsonDocument.Parse("{ docs: { $slice: [ \"$docs\", { $multiply: [ -1, { $ceil: { $divide: [ \"$count.total\", 2 ] } } ] } ] } }"));

var replaceRoot = new BsonValueAggregateExpressionDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>("$docs");

var result = Col.Aggregate()
                .Match(q)
                .Facet<BsonDocument>(new[] { countFacet, matchFacet })
                .Unwind("count")
                .Project(projection)
                .Unwind("docs")
                .ReplaceRoot(replaceRoot)
                .ToList<BsonDocument>();
```